# How to prevent Server Down

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, rml

Please help me on this problem.

I'm using OpenERP 6.0.

**The case is like this**:

1. I have login **GTK** client with `2` users.
2. At the same time, I using this `2` users to print the same report (ex: abc report). (Note: this report have more than `10000` record)
3. Then the gtk of that `2` users become not responding and the server directly **not working** (down)
4. After that, I try to opened a new gtk client, but the gtk is not responding.

**The temporary solution is**:

1. I connect to server and kill the service.
2. After that, I start the service again.

Please help me to prevent this server down problem? While this is not a good solution

Comment: you want to avoid a Serverdown problem or prevent the serverdown problem?

Comment: hi girish, i want to prevent it.

Comment: Be proactive - if you see errors or frequent high loads, investigate, see what's causing it so that you can fix it before it kills the server. Optimizing also helps.

Comment: Hi girish, thanks for your suggestion. but because of i just found it always loading n loading and after that server directly not working anymore, that's why i must kill the process on server.
now, i was assump that if it because of not enough memory. So, i will try to increase the memory for GTK Open ERP.